# Neo4j hierarchical comments architecture and best practices

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

In my Spring Boot/Neo4j application I have a big tree of Neo4j nodes and now I would like to implement hierarchical comments for each of these node.

I plan to create a new `Comment` entity and right now have a few questions about the solution design.

Comments in my application must be hierarchical so I plan to create something like this:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Comment {

    @RelatedTo(type = CONTAINS, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Decision> childComments = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Also, I plan to use comments for different types, for example for `Post`, `User`, `Company` and so on.

Should I create some interface, let's say `Commentable` and implement this interface in `Post`, `User`, `Company` classes ?

If so, it would be possible to use this interface(not a 
`@NodeEntity`) in my `Comment` class? For example:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Comment {

    @RelatedTo(type = CONTAINS, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Decision> childComments = new HashSet<>();

    @RelatedTo(type = CONTAINS, direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    Commentable owner;

}
```

Also, if an each comment will know about its owner, how to determine for example a first comment on a certain node(root element for comments tree for a certain `Commentable` node) ? Maybe by a comment creation date ?

Is there in Neo4j/Cypher/SDN a way to fetch a comments tree directly by querying the data or it should be implement in code(in the business logic of my application) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an abstract base class *Commentable*, annotating it with *@NodeEntity*, and putting in that all methods that are common to commentables, i.e. *getComments* and so on. 
Concrete commentables just extend *Commentable*, you don't need to annotate with *@NodeEntity*.
The second question is somewhat ambiguous: does commentables own one single root comment or do they own a list of root comments, each of them being the root of a comment tree?
I suppose the latter, so I suggest to link commentables to root comments and access comment trees from them.

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class Commentable {

    @RelatedTo(type = COMMENTABLE_COMMENTS, direction = Direction.BOTH)
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();

}

@NodeEntity
public class Comment {

    @RelatedTo(type = CHILD_COMMENTS, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Comment> childComments = new HashSet<>();

    @RelatedTo(type = COMMENTABLE_COMMENTS, direction = Direction.BOTH)
    Commentable owner;

}
```

You can fetch a given comment tree with a query like the following:

```
MATCH (comment {key: {value}})-[:CHILD_COMMENTS*]->(child)
```

There I'm supposing that you already fetched the root comment and that comments have some key attribute to uniquely identify them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your assumption is correct - `Commentable` owns a list of root comments. So, how to fetch all comments trees(not a single tree)  for this certain Commentable? Make a query based on `commentable.id` for example ?

Comment: Yes, could be `MATCH (commentable:{id: {id})<-[:COMMENTABLE_COMMENTS]->(comment)-[:CHILD_COMMENTS*]->(child)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on **remigio** answer I have improved solution a little bit:

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class Commentable {

    @RelatedTo(type = COMMENTED_ON, direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();

}

@NodeEntity
public class Comment extends Commentable {

    @RelatedTo(type = COMMENTED_ON, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Commentable commentable;

    private String text;
}
```